# Google Embedded Charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I want to use the Google Line chart in a way that there should be multiple lines being plotted, having multiple Data Points on each line. And when i click any data point then a small popup opens 0n that point which shows the further details regarding that point..

Comment: What kind of data are you plotting, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

Google offers two distinct charting APIs. One is the [Google Charts API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/), and the other is the [Google Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/index.html).

The Charts API will return an image, rendered on Google's servers. However this image is obviously not interactive, as you can see below:

[image: Google Charts API]

On the other hand, the Visualization API is able to render interactive charts and other visualizations. From what you describe, it looks like you might be interested in something like the following:

- [Visualization Gallery: Area Chart](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/areachart.html)